# link dates in between consecutive years

Tags: sas

Suppose the following:

> ```
>       data have;
>       input ID :$20. Start :date9. End :date9. Label :$20.;
>       format start end yymmdd10.;
>       cards;
>       0001 01JAN2021 01JAN2021 A
>       0001 07MAR2021 07MAR2021 C
>       0001 08MAR2021 11MAR2021 A
>       0001 20OCT2021 31DEC2021 A
>       0002 06FEB2018 13FEB2018 C
>       0002 27DEC2018 31DEC2018 C
>       0001 02JAN2022 18MAY2022 A
>       0001 22MAY2022 08AUG2022 B
>       0002 01JAN2019 10JAN2019 C
>       0003 19MAY2000 22MAY2000 C
>       .......................;
> ```

I'm looking for the following output:
data want;

> ```
>   input ID :$20. Start :date9. End :date9. Label :$20.;
>   format start end yymmdd10.;
>   cards;
>   0001 01JAN2021 01JAN2021 A
>   0001 07MAR2021 07MAR2021 C
>   0001 08MAR2021 11MAR2021 A
>   0001 20OCT2021 18MAY2022 A
>   0001 22MAY2022 08AUG2022 B
>   0002 06FEB2018 13FEB2018 C
>   0002 27DEC2018 10JAN2019 C
>   0003 19MAY2000 22MAY2000 C
>   ...................;
> ```

In other words, for each ID, and for each Label I would like to sum periods only if from one year to the next one dates differ at max for 1 day. For example for 0001 from 31DEC2021 to 02JAN2022 there is only a gap of 1 day and hence periods must be added resulting in 1 period. The same for consecutive lags. This must be done for periods in between two years. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
  input ID :$20. (Start End)(:date9.) Label $;
  format Start End date9.;
cards;
0001 01JAN2021 01JAN2021 A
0001 20OCT2021 31DEC2021 A
0002 06FEB2018 13FEB2018 C
0002 27DEC2018 31DEC2018 C
0001 02JAN2022 18MAY2022 A
0001 22MAY2022 08AUG2022 B
0002 01JAN2019 10JAN2019 C
0003 19MAY2000 22MAY2000 C
;

proc sort data = have;
   by ID Label;
run;

data temp(drop = s);
   set have;
   by ID;
   set have(firstobs = 2 keep = start rename = start = s) have(obs = 1 drop = _all_);
   if last.ID then s = .;
   n = s - end;
run;

data want(drop = s _start n days);
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (n > 2 | last.ID);
      set temp;
      by ID;
      if _N_ = 1 then _start = Start;
   end;

   Start = ifn(_start = ., Start, _start);
   days = End - Start + 1;
run;
```

Comment: thank you dottor Clemmersen for suggestion. It was already asked and I already tested your help but unfortunately in this case it does not work. I edited the question so that you can appreciate where it fails. Specifically it combines consecutive days even if the label differs.

Comment: by changing: have(obs = 1 drop = _all_) and if _N_ <  2 then _start=Start; it works!